# PHP Redirect missing points

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my php login form, it seems like something is wrong with it, I have a lot of codes to post so I'm gonna start from the simplest one, basically the function Redirect is not redirecting to "login.php" but to "loginphp", this seems quite strange and that could explain why the rest of the code is not working, here's the code

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {



} else {
   redirect(login.php);
}
?>
```

And here's the redirect function

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

So as I explained before it's redirecting to http://host.com/loginphp instead of http://host.com/login.php . Thanks in advance!

Comment: quote it redirect('login.php');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it in your code from

```
redirect(login.php);
```

to

```
redirect("login.php");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, anyway I have still some issues with my login.php form, I will post another question to resolve them.